# why simple query work in workbench but dont work in IDE

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, workbench

i got problems with this query on hibernate

```
select 
       reservations.user_id,
       reservations.start_day,
       reservations.end_day,
       lake_id,
       peg_number 
from reservations 
left join pegs on reservations.peg_id = pegs.id 
left join lakes l on pegs.lake_id = l.id 
where lake_id = :lakeId
```

on workbench working fine but doesnt want work in my IDE

Database Structure

1. ```
     **reservations** id,created_at,end_day,start_day,peg_id,user_id
   ```
2. ```
           **pegs** id,peg_name,peg_number,lake_id
   ```
3. ```
           **lakes** id,name,city,lat,lon,user_id
   ```

Comment: and can you also post the complete error message and the code also

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.

Comment: i think somethink is wrong with aliases but doesnt know what

Comment: Please  post table description  as well

Comment: edot your post with new information and we can't guiess which id field is here the problem, sso post the create table of all and again post the java code aswell

Comment: @DawidSieradzki and `lakes` table ?

Comment: Use alias for pegs as well. left join pegs p and then p.id

Comment: @Alien still doesnt work